# How to print the length size of the following line

Tags: awk, formatting

I would like  to modify a file by including the size of following line using awk.
My file is like this:

```
>AAAS:1220136:1220159:-:0::NW_015494524.1:1220136-1220159(-)  
ATGTCGATGCTCGATC  
>AAAS::1215902:1215986:-:1::NW_015494524.1:1215902-1215986(-) 
ATGCGATGCTAGCTAGCTCGAT  
>AAAS:1215614:1215701:-:1::NW_015494524.1:1215614-1215701(-)
ATGCCGCGACGCAGCACCCGACGCGCAG
```

I am using awk to modify it to have the following format:

```
>Assembly_AAAS_1_16  
ATGTCGATGCTCGATC  
>Assembly_AAAS_2_22  
ATGCGATGCTAGCTAGCTCGAT  
>Assembly_AAAS_3_28  
ATGCCGCGACGCAGCACCCGACGCGCAG
```

I have used awk to modify the first part.

```
awk -F":" -v i=1 '/>/{print ">Assembly_" $1 "_" val i "_";i++;next} {print length($0)} 1' infile | sed -e "s/_>/_/g" > outfile
```

I can use  print length($0) but how to print it in the same line?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that it should be `Assembly_AAAS_3_28`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** Since OP has changed the sample data again so adding this code now.

```
awk -v val="Assembly_AAAS_" '/>/{++i;val=">"val i "_";next} {sub(/ +$/,"");print val length($0) ORS $0}'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -v val="Assembly_AAAS_" '/>/{++i;val=">"val i "_";next} {print val length($1) ORS $0;}'  Input_file
```

Above will remove spaces from last of the lines of Input_file, in case you don't need it then remove `sub(/ +$/,"");` part from above code please.

---

***EDIT:*** As per OP changed solution now.

```
awk -v i=1 -v val=">Assembly_GeneName1_" -v val1="_sizeline" '/>/{value="\047" val i val1;i++;next} {print value length($0) ORS $0}' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -v i=1 -v val=">Assembly_GeneName1_" -v val1="_sizeline" '
/>/{  value="\047" val i val1;
      i++;
      next}
{
      print value length($0) ORS $0
}
'   Input_file
```

---

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk -v i="" -v j=2 '/>/{print "\047>Assembly_GeneName1_"++i"_sizeline"j;j+=2;next} 1'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
awk -v i=1 -v j=2 -v val=">Assembly_GeneName1_" -v val1="_sizeline" '/>/{print "\047" val i val1 j;j+=2;i++;next} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks. But sorry in fact I want a value for size line, which is the number of character of the line after:

Comment: @Nico64, please post expected output in code tags in your post.

Comment: I have modify the output.

Comment: I tried this  `awk -F":"  -v i=""  '/>/{print ">Assembly_"$1"_"++i"_;next} 1' file`

Comment: @Nico64, try my EDIT solution now.

Comment: ok. I retry and it is close. However the part `{ print value length($0) ORS $0}` is printed in an other line.  I have used: `awk -F":" -v i=1 '/>/{print ">Assembly_" $1 "_" val i "_";i++;next} {print b length($0) ORS $0}' `

Comment: @Nico64, not sure if your actual data is different from sample shown? please confirm once it is working fine for me for shown sample.

Comment: I have updated the input to show how they are. I used this command: `awk -F":" -v i=1 '/>/{print ">Assembly_" $1 "_" val i "_";i++;next} {print length($0)} 1' infile | sed -e "s/_>/_/g" > outfile`

Comment: @Nico64, please post in your post what is not working, from your comment it is not clear.

Comment: the value of print length($0) is printed on a separate line and not at the end of the first line.

Comment: @Nico64, why you are not using the same solution which I have given, please don't create confusions, try with my EDIT solution and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: @Nico64, since you changed sample data completely, kindly check my EDIT2 now and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @kvantour, :) not your mistake, OP changed samples multiple times :)

Comment: @kvantour, in EDIT2 you could see nothing is there.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 actually, you might use `{print val length($1) ORS $0}`, then you don't need the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

What you are dealing with is a beautiful example of records which are not lines. `awk` is a record parser and by default, a record is defined to be a line. With `awk` you can define a record to be a block of text using the record separator `RS`.

> **`RS` :** The first character of the string value of `RS` shall be the input record separator; a `<newline>` by default. If `RS` contains more
>   than one character, the results are unspecified. If `RS` is null, then
>   records are separated by sequences consisting of a `<newline>` plus one
>   or more blank lines, leading or trailing blank lines shall not result
>   in empty records at the beginning or end of the input, and a `<newline>`
>   shall always be a field separator, no matter what the value of `FS` is.

So the goal is to define the record to be

```
AAAS:1220136:1220159:-:0::NW_015494524.1:1220136-1220159(-)  
ATGTCGATGCTCGATC
```

And this can be done by defining the `RS="\n<"`. Furthremore we will use `\n` as a field separator `FS`. This way you can get the requested length as `length($2)` and the count by using the record count `NR`.

A simple `awk` script is then:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n<"; FS=OFS="\n"}
     {$1=">Assembly_AAAS_"NR"_"length($2)}
     {print $1,$2}' <file>
```

This will do exactly what you want.

**note:** we use `print $1,$2` and not `print $0` as the last record might have 3 fields (if the last char of the file is a newline). This would imply that you would have an extra empty line at the end of your file.

If you want to pick the `AAAS` string out of `$1` you can use `substr($1,1,match($1,":")-1)` to pick it up. This results in this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n<"; FS=OFS="\n"}
     {$1=">Assembly_"substr($1,1,match($1,":")-1)"_"NR"_"length($2)}
     {print $1,$2}' <file>
```

Finally, be aware that the above solution only works if there are no spaces in `$2`, if you want to change that, you can do this :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n<"; FS=OFS="\n"}
     { gsub(/[[:blank:]]/,"",$2);
       $1=">Assembly_"substr($1,1,match($1,":")-1)"_"NR"_"length($2)
     }
     { print $1,$2 }' <file>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes Iam using $1 for AAAS because I will run a loop for thousand of files which have a different gene name other than AAAS in this example. I used also a | then `sed` to remove the > at the start of my geneName.